how do i fix this problem in office chair
It probably happened during transportation- the shaft has disengaged from the mount and I am finding it hard to put it back. What is the correct way to fix this ?


Probably a press fit, so some force will be needed.  When pressing it in, you want it perfectly straight.  Might want to use two short 3x3s or 4x4s with a half circle cut out to fit the shaft.  Two cargo straps with tighteners should press it in

Furniture repair is off topic here as not part of home improvement. Please see the [help].

remove the seat (unscrew it)
use rubber hammer to knock it in,
if you do not have a rubber hammer, use a scrap wood on top of the shaft so not to damage it during hammering
recommended is to remove the wheels temporary before hammering
reinstall the seat and the wheels –
